# Xcode 12 list won't show up and error 'nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed'

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm getting a strange error with my test project, `nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed Error`. ContentView.swift below, App.swift hasn't been touched. It's supposed to just grab JSON from a local web server, and display it in a list. Does anyone know what is going on here? I've been googling but haven't found a solution.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyAPI {
  static public var address = "http://localhost:9000"
}

struct Post: Codable, Identifiable {
    public var id: Int
    public var username: String
    public var link: String
}

class FetchPosts: ObservableObject {
  // 1.
  @Published var posts = [Post]()
     
    init() {
        let url = URL(string: MyAPI.address)!
        // 2.
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
            do {
                if let postsData = data {
                    // 3.
                    let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: postsData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.posts = decodedData
                        print(self.posts)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var fetch = FetchPosts()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Test")
            // 2.
            List(fetch.posts) { post in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(post.username)
                    Text("\(post.link)") // print boolean
                        .font(.system(size: 11))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to check for the low hanging fruit first, have you checked the network entitlement in your app's sandbox to make sure can make outgoing connections?  `Project Settings` -> `Signing & Capabilities` -> `App Sandbox` -> `Outgoing Connections (Client)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not related to your request and just [console noise](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-firebase-connection/41632/5). Add `NSAppTransportSecurity` to your info.plist, add key `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` and set it to true. Also, if your app is for Mac, allow outgoing connections in Signing and Capabilites

Comment: Ah, thanks! Turns out there was no data because of an error in the JSON formatting.